# Error in msgrcv: Invalid Arguments

Tags: c, unix, ipc

I am writing a code in C on a unix system. I have created a message queue server. Each time I receive a new message I fork and the child process handles the new client. The server waits for new client. Here's the code.

```c
for (;;)
 {
      struct my_msgbuf buf;

      if (msgrcv (msqid, &(buf.mtype), sizeof (buf), 1, 0) == -1)
      perror ("msgrcv");


    if((pid = fork())<0)
    perror("fork");


    if(pid==0)
    {
     //child code
    }
}
```

Now the code works for the first iteration but on the second iteration msgrcv gives the following error -
msgrcv: Invalid Arguments instead of waiting for new messages.

Answer (score 1):

`msgrcv` does take a `msgsz` parameter, but it's not the size of a `struct my_msgbuf`, rather, it's the number of bytes in the `mtext[]` field of the structure.

You aren't really supposed to use `struct msgbuf` directly, I think. It would be normal to define your own with appropriate space. The way you have it, your `buf` declaration allocates only 1 byte, and then the code tells the kernel that you have `sizeof buf` bytes, which you don't. As a result, the code is said to invoke *Undefined Behavior* or UB.

This may or may not explain the `EINVAL` but one should always fix the known bugs and retest because UB taints further analysis...

Comment: The code doesn't show an assignment to `mtype`. Is it getting set reasonably?

Comment: Sure, but are you setting to a positive number identifying a message type in a queue?  Not sure what Unix you are on but on my linux man page is says the following about sources of EINVAL: Invalid  msqid  value,  or non-positive mtype value, or invalid
              msgsz value (less than 0 or greater than the system value  MSG‐
              MAX).

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with the above code. Firstly here

```
msgrcv (msqid, &(buf.mtype), sizeof (buf), 1, 0)
```

second argument `&(buf.mtype)` is incorrect as process is expected to receive complete `buf` not only `buf.mtype`. If  `struct my_msgbuf` looks like

```
struct my_msgbuf {
       long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0 */
       char mtext[1];    /* message data */

};
```

then `msgrcv()` should look like

```
msgrcv (msqid, &buf, sizeof(buf), 1, 0);
```

> Now the code works for the first iteration but on the second iteration
>   msgrcv gives the following error - msgrcv: Invalid Arguments instead
>   of waiting for new messages ?

That's because `msgrcv()` executes before `fork()`, what if parent process doesn't executes `msgsnd()` ?

To resolve this you should keep `msgrcv()` statement inside child process. Also run the for loop inside child & parent process not outside child/parent block. For e.g

```
struct my_msgbuf buf;

if((pid = fork())<0)
{
    /* @TODO set the buf.mtype here  */
    perror("fork");
    for(;;) /* use loop inside parent process to write into MQ continuously */
    {
        /* @TODO scan the data into  buf.mtext */
        /* @TODO msgsnd statement */
    }
}
else
{
    for(;;) /* use loop inside child process to read from MQ continuously */
    {
        if (msgrcv (msqid, &buf, sizeof (buf), 1, 0) == -1)
            perror ("msgrcv");
        printf("received data : %s\n", buf.mtext);
    }
}
```

Comment: `msgrcv` requires sizeof(struct) - sizeof(long).